# When can we find holomorphic bijections between annuli?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, teichmueller-theory

I'm self-studying some complex analysis, and apparently holomorphic bijections between two annuli exist precisely when the ratios of the radii are the same. More exactly, if $A_{\sigma,\rho}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\sigma<|z|<\rho\}$, then there is a holomorphic bijection between $A_{\sigma,\rho}$ and $A_{\sigma',\rho'}$ iff $\rho/\sigma=\rho'/\sigma'$.

Is there a reference where this fact is proven? Or can a proof be included here if it's not overly involved? Thanks.

Comment: This is exercise 1 on page 249 of Ahlfohrs, after both Riemann mapping and a fairly deep look at harmonic functions and the Dirichlet problem. The section is titled Canonical Mappings of Multiply Connected Regions.

Comment: You should find this in your favorite complex analysis book. Mine is Greene & Krantz: Function Theory of One Complex Variable (It's in chapter 7)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This result (sometimes called Schottky's theorem) can be proved without any heavy machinery like Riemann mapping or even Schwarz reflection. I give two versions of the proof, with comments at the end.

**Claim**. If there exists a bijective holomorphic map $f: A_{r,R}\to A_{s,S}$, then $S/s\ge R/r$.

Note that we actually get equality by considering the inverse.

*Proof*. Normalize to $r=s=1$. By composing $f$ with inversion, we can make sure that $|f(z)|\to 1$ as $|z|\to1$. For $1<t<R$ let $A(t)$ denote the area within the Jordan curve $f(\{z:|z|=t\})$. There is a standard way to relate the area to the coefficient of the Laurent series $f(z)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} c_n z^n$: namely, use [Green's formula for area](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreensTheorem.html) in complex notation. 
$$A(t)=\frac{1}{2i} \int_{0}^{2\pi}  f(te^{i\theta}) \bar f(te^{i\theta})\, d\theta = \pi \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}  n|c_n|^2t^{2n}$$ 
Since $A(1+)=\pi$, we have 
$$(1)\qquad\qquad \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}  n|c_n|^2=1.$$
From here the proof can proceed in at least two ways.

*Version I: stick to area*. Using (1), write
$$A(t)-\pi t^2=\pi t^2 \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}  n|c_n|^2(t^{2n-2}-1)\ge0$$
where the inequality holds term-wise. Hence $A(R-)\ge \pi R^2$, which implies $S\ge R$. **QED**

*Version II: use $L^2$ norm*. For $1<t<R$ define
$$U(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi t} \int_{|z|=t} |f(z)|^2|dz|$$ 
Again, this can be put in terms of coefficients either by direct computation with $|f|^2=f\bar f$, or by Parseval's identity: 
 $U(t)= \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} |c_n|^2 t^{2n}$.
Since $U(1+)=1$ and 
$$U'(t)-2t= 2t\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}  n|c_n|^2 (t^{2n-2}-1)\ge 0 $$
it follows that $U(R-)\ge R^2$. But $|f|\le S$, which implies $S\ge R$. **QED**

Comments: the idea of relating coefficients to area as in (1) goes back to [Gronwall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall%27s_area_theorem#Gronwall.27s_area_theorem). In the context of this problem it was used by Pólya and Szegő in [Problems and Theorems in Analysis II](http://books.google.com/books?id=AVbrKFKGtPkC), part IV, problem 83 on page 15. Their solution is essentially Version I. I learned it from a [short note](http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.2763) by Pietro Poggi-Corradini.

The idea of using $L^2$ norm instead of area may look counterproductive, since Version II is longer. But it is a more robust argument, which works [for harmonic maps](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2011-24-02/S0894-0347-2010-00685-6/home.html) as well. Robert Burckel and Pietro pointed out Version II to us as a simplification of $L^2$ argument specialized to holomorphic maps.

Comment: This is awesome. Did this argument appear in one of their papers?

Comment: @t.b. I rewrote the proof[s] and attempted to put their history in better perspective.

Comment: Thanks again for this great answer!

Comment: Hey thanks LVK!

Comment: I think it should be $f'(te^{i\theta}) e^{i\theta}=nf(te^{i\theta})$ instead of just $f(te^{i\theta})$ in the integral defining $A(t)$.