# Conformal map between annulii

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there any conformal map between $D_1= \lbrace z \in \mathcal{C} \; ; \; 1 \leq |z| \leq 2 \rbrace$ and $D_2 = \lbrace z \in \mathcal{C} \; ; \; 1 \leq |z| \leq 3 \rbrace$.

By the Schottky theorem there is not. But I am looking for some other  way. Some hints will be usefull.

Comment: You mean you are looking for a proof of the Schottky theorem? The special case of these two annuli is not any easier than the general result.

Comment: Think...can you preserve angles?

Comment: The proof will help, but do you have any suggestion for this special case?

Comment: Two rings $Δ(0,r_1,R_1),Δ(0,r_2,R_2)$  are conformal equivalent iff $R_2/r_2=R_1/r_1$. Now the proof is one and a half pages long.search it on the net,you will find it for sure

Comment: One proof is (almost) physical: capacity (in 2 dimensions) is a conformal invariant; the capacity of an annulus is $\log R/r$.

Comment: Why is capacity a conformal invariant?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg It's defined as the infimum of $\int |\nabla u|^2$ over smooth real-valued functions with boundary values $0$ and $1$ on each boundary component. Then one has to check that the Dirichlet integral $\int |\nabla u|^2$ is conformally invariant. And calculate the capacity of circular annulus, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @user103402.

Answer (score 9):

One approach to this problem is to use the Schwarz reflection principle. Suppose $$f : \{1<|z|<3\}\to \{1<|z|<2\}$$ is   conformal. Replacing $f$ with $f(2/z)$ if necessary, we can assume that $f$ takes one inner boundary (unit circle) to the other inner boundary (also unit circle). The reflection across the inner circle extends $f$ to a conformal map $$\{3^{-1}<|z|<3\}\to \{2^{-1}<|z|<2\}$$ Extending over the inner circle again, we get a map $$\{3^{-3}<|z|<3\}\to \{2^{-3}<|z|<2\}$$ and so on. The result is a conformal map between punctured disks. The singularity at $0$ is removable, by boundedness. Being holomorphic, $f$ must be locally Lipschitz; it satisfies an inequality of the form $|f(z)|\le C|z|$ near $0$. But this contradicts it taking $3^{-n}$ to $2^{-n}$ for infinitely many integer values of $n$.

A   different approach is presented in  [When can we find holomorphic bijections between annuli?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/133578/)

Comment: Why must $f$ extend continuously to the boundary in that way?

Comment: @Potato because it lifts to a biholomorphic map between the upper half plane to itself which we know takes the form (az+b)/(cuz+d) for a,b,c,d real. This clearly extends continuously to the boundary.