# Proof of a necessary and sufficient condition between annuli centered at the origin

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

What is a simple way to prove that two annuli $A_1 = {z: r_1 < |z| < R_1}$ and $A_2 = {z: r_2 < |z| < R_2}$ are conformally equivalent if and only if $R_1/r_1 = R_2/r_2$, using standard results of complex analysis?

I'm not looking for a concise proof so much as one that uses elementary concepts.

Comment: One direction is fairly easy. Have you made any progress on either direction?

Comment: No, I'm more interested in the other direction too...

Comment: And of [Conformal map between annulii](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/558153). Please search before asking.

Comment: But is there any way to do it without the Schwarz reflection principle, or Green's formula for area?