Annulus biholomorphically equivalence

Prove that if $w = \varphi \left( z\right)$ is biholomorphic from $D = \left\{  {z \in  C : {r}_{1} < \left| z\right|  < {r}_{2}}\right\}$ onto $G = \left\{  {w \in  C : {R}_{1} < \left| w\right|  < {R}_{2}}\right\}$, where, $0 < {r}_{1} < {r}_{2} < \infty, 0 < {R}_{1} < {R}_{2} <$ $\infty$, then $\frac{{r}_{1}}{{r}_{2}} = \frac{{R}_{1}}{{R}_{2}}$, and $\varphi \left( z\right)  = {\mathrm{e}}^{\mathrm{i}\theta }\frac{{R}_{1}z}{{r}_{1}}$ or $\varphi \left( z\right)  = {\mathrm{e}}^{\mathrm{i}\theta }\frac{{R}_{2}{r}_{1}}{z}, \theta  \in  \mathbf{R}$.

My attempt: Let $\varphi(z)=\sum_{i\ integers}a_iz^i$, then the area of $G$ can be calculated in two ways:
$$\pi(R_2^2-R_1^2)=\pi \sum_{i\ integers}i |a_i|^2(r_2^{2i}-r_1^{2i}).$$
What should we do next? The tems in RHD are all $\geq 0$!

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1873568/42969 and the linked questions.
