# Are $\{ z: 1<|z|<2\}$ and $\{z: |z|>1\}$ conformally equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I don't know whether a ring, i.e. the domain $\{z: 1<|z|<2\}$ and the exterior of the closed unit disk $\{z: |z|>1\}$ are conformally equivalent?

I have tried to look on some topological properties, which must be preserved by conformal mapping. They are not simply connected so I can't use Riemann's Theorem.
I would like to find a specific conformal mapping between them. 
I believe that it is possible to map the boundary of $D_2(0)$ to infinity somehow.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is equivalent to asking if $A = \{z: 1<|z|<2\}$ and
$B = \{w: 0<|w|<1\}$ are conformally equivalent, and they are not:

The conformal mapping $f : B \to A $ would have a removable singularity at $w=0$,
and this easily leads to a contradiction (consider both cases $f(0) \in \partial A$ and $f(0) \in A$).

Generally, two annuli are conformally equivalent if and only if the
ratio between outer and inner radius is the same, see for example

- [Conformity of two concentric annuli](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1873568/conformity-of-two-concentric-annuli)
- [Conformal map between annulii](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/558153/conformal-map-between-annulii)
- [When can we find holomorphic bijections between annuli?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133578/when-can-we-find-holomorphic-bijections-between-annuli)

for different proofs.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that it would hold for ratio=$\infty$ as well.

Comment: I can see that the $f(0) \in A$ case is bad because then $f$ is no longer injective, but I don't see with certainty why $f(0) \in \partial A$ is problematic. Is it because the rest of $\partial A$ besides the point to which $f(0)$ maps to is not in the image of $f$?

Comment: @JoshuaSiktar: If $f(0) \in \partial A$ then either $|f|$ or $|1/f|$ has a maximum at $z=0$, and the maximum modulus principle would imply that $f$ is constant.