# Proving two domains not to be conformally equivalent and property of holomorphic map

Tags: complex-analysis, problem-solving

I am trying questions in complex analysis of an institute in which I dont study . My course was marred by a non serious professor and hence I have to study from resources online and hence I could not have good problem solving skills in complex analysis .

Questions :1. Prove that  {z:0<|z|<1} and {z:r<|z|<R} are not conformally equivalent if r>0 .

I have studied defination of conformally equivalent and related theorems from Ponnusamy Silvermann but I am unable to think about which result I should use .

2. Show that if a holomorphic map f maps U(Unit disc with centre z=0) into itself it need not have a fixed point in U even if it extends to a continuous map of the closure of U onto itself .

For this question I dont have any clue on how it should be solved.

It is my humble request to you to help as I cant ask for help in questions anywhere else . I admit that I for now is not able to provide reasonable attempt but I have studied from book (Ponnusamy Silvermann) in detail.
Thanks!!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2815107/are-z-1z2-and-z-z1-conformally-equivalent for the first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1: the result is easy since if $f:\mathbb D^* \to A(r,R)$ is a holomorphic map, $f$ is bounded hence $0$ is a removable singularity, which means that $f$ is a map from the unit disc to the annulus; if $f$ is $1-1$ on the punctured disc, it is $1-1$ on the full disc ($f(0)=f(w)$ means that some neighborhood of $0$ and $w$ are mapped to the same open set around the common value) and it obviously cannot be onto since $f(\partial D)$ is connected

For 2: take $\frac{z-r}{1-rz}, 0<r<1$ which is an automorphism of the closed unit disc and has its two fixed points at $\pm 1$; the result is sharp since the [Brouwer fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem) shows that any continuous map of the closed unit disc to itself has fixed points

(here the result is obvious but in general, for any Mobius transform, the equation $f(z)=z$ becomes a quadratic after eliminating denominators so it cannot have more than two solutions)

Comment: can you please tell how does in answer of 1 , f being bounded implies 0 is a removable singularity ?

Comment: This is one of the first results in complex analysis - isolated singularities are removable, poles or essential, and they are removable precisely when the function is bounded on a small neighborhood of them - proof: take $g=z^2f$; it is obvious that $g$ is differentiable in the full disc with $g'(0)=0$ since $g(0)=0, g(z)/z \to 0$ by the boundness of $f$; hence (this is a very strong hence encompassing the power of complex analysis) $g$ is analytic; $g(0)=g'(0)=0$, so $g(z)=z^2h(z)$ for some analytic $h$; so extending $f(0)=h(0)$ gives the required anlaytic extension of $f$ to zero

Comment: I am really sorry man but I am  not able to understand  in 1. how it can't be onto as f($\delta D$) is connected . Can you please help me I want to understand the solution.

Comment: @Cornad In 2 . we are asked to gve an example of a question which doesn't have fixed points and you gave example of an automophism having fixed points. and you are using  So, It question 2. wrong  as if I use Brower fixed point theorem then I am getting the existence of fixed point.

Comment: for 2, there is no fixed point in the open unit disc, which is what the problem asks; as noted there is always a fixed point in the closed unit disc by classical theorems; for 1, the connectedness of the boundary of the unit disc and the fact that $f$ is assumed to be injective inside, means that the image of the unit disc has a connected boundary and the annulus plainly has not such, so it cannot be the image; that is true for even a continuous injective map by topological considerations only