# A problem about conformal equivalence in complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove that the punctured disk  $\left\{0<\left|x\right|<2\right\}$ and the annulus $\left\{1<\left|x\right|<2\right\}$ are not conformally equaivalent.

I know that a map is conformal if and only if it is biholomorphic. So in order to prove the desired result,we can prove that there is no one-to-one mapping which is also holomorphic between punctured disk and annulus. But I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: See this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133578/when-can-we-find-holomorphic-bijections-between-annuli

Comment: You can compute at the group of conformal self-maps for each set; they will differ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't need the most general result stated in the comment above. Note that if $f$ is such an equivalence, then $0$ is a removable singularity. Extend $f$ to the whole disk, and consider two cases- the image of $0$ being on the boundary and on the inside of the annulus.

Edit: The results that'll help - maximum/minimum modulus principle and the Open Mapping Theorem.

Comment: which theorem can I turn to in order to prove that neither of  two cases you have mentioned above can happen? It may seem stupid to ask that.Please

Comment: @mike, I've edited the answer with some hints.

Comment: Thank you very much.I really appreciate your kindly help.