# Holomorphic function between $\{z\in \mathbb{C}: 1\leq |z|\leq 4\}$ and $\{z\in \mathbb{C}: 1\leq |z|\leq 2\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Does there exist a holomorphic function $h$ that sends the set $\{z\in \mathbb{C}: 1\leq |z|\leq 4\}$ to the set $\{z\in \mathbb{C}: 1\leq |z|\leq 2\}$?

I tried proving it but I could not. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: So, according to you, what is actually the meaning of $\{1\leq |z|\leq 4\}$? And what is the meaning of $|z|$?

Comment: @imranfat thanks for your obervation... I update my post. Thanks.

Comment: you mean a biholomorphic map ? (otherwise $h(z) = 3/2$ works)

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133578/when-can-we-find-holomorphic-bijections-between-annuli.

Comment: @Diego1802 So what are your (other) conditions on the map ? surjective at least, I gather, but how about bijective?, covering?

Answer (score -1):

It depends upon what other properties you want of the map? If you don't care about how the image is covered or what happens to boundaries then you may do it by abstract non-sense (applying the Riemann mapping theorem).

If, however, you want a genuine $d$-fold covering map ($h$ should be locally injective and each point in the image should have precisely $d$ preimages) then this is not possible, due to what is know as the modulus of an annulus.
The modulus of an annulus is an invariant under bi-holomorphic maps. For a $d$-fold covering map the modulus is multiplied by $d$.

For an annulus $A_R=\{ 1 \leq |z| \leq R\}$ the modulus is $\log R$ and a $d$-fold covering map, like $z\mapsto z^d$  gives an image of modulus $d\log R$. One checks e.g. that $\log R^d = d \log R$.

So in particular, $A_2$ may be mapped to $A_4$ (by $z^2$, but you probably noticed this), whereas the converse is not possible.

Comment: you are allowed to explain what you mean in simple words ($d$-fold, $d\log R$, ..)

Comment: The map $z\mapsto z^2$ maps $A_2$ to $A_4$ such that each point in $A_4$ has precisely $d=2$ preimages. The derivative of the map is $2z$ which never vanishes in $A_2$ (so the map is locally injective).

Comment: so what ? how is it a proof ? (look at the link given by lhf)

Comment: Ok, I understand your question. $d$ is an integer but mapping the annulus of modulus $\log 4$ to $\log 2$ would require $d=1/2$ which is not possible.