# Nonexistence of a conformal mapping between annuli

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume that $f:A(1,R_1) \to A(1,R_2)$ was a conformal mapping, where $1<R_2<R_1$. Consider the iterates $f_1=f$ and $f_n=f \circ f_{n-1}$. By Montel's Theorem, there exists a subsequence of the family $\mathscr{F}=\{f_n\}$ converging uniformly to a function $F$ on compact subsets of $A(1,R_1)$. I get stuck on the following question: The set $F(A(1,R_1))$ cannot contain a nonempty open set. How can one start the proof?

Comment: maybe this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133578/when-can-we-find-holomorphic-bijections-between-annuli

Comment: @JustDroppedIn I have read the link you provided, but it seems that it used methods different from the one I asked here.

Comment: I know, that's why I upvoted your post