Finite cylinders are not biholomorphic Riemann surfaces
I have trouble verifying this:
for $r > 1$, let $C_r = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \ | \ 1 < |z| < r\}$. As an open set of $\mathbb{C}$, it is a Riemann surface. It want to show that for $1 < r < r'$, $C_r$ and $C_{r'}$ are not biholomorphic (hence we will have an infinity of non-simply connected Riemann surfaces in $\mathbb{C}$ up to isomorphism).
I don't know how to begin. I get that $C_r$ will be biholomorphic to $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \ | \ \frac{r'}{r} < |z| < r'\}$ thanks to a homothety, I have trouble understanding why the girth of the cylinder matters to holomorphic properties.
I have already proven, with the help of Riemann's extension theorem, that $C_r$ is not biholomorphic to $C_{\infty} = \mathbb{C}^*$, but the idea seems to be different here.
Any advice?

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/133578/42969 and the linked questions. Two annuli are conformally equivalent if and only if their ratio between outer and inner radius is the same.
